# Convert svg data into pdf using SVGtoPDF (SVG-to-PDFKit)

Tags: svg, fabricjs, pdfkit, node-pdfkit

I am using SVGtoPDF npm library to get svg element on pdf but for following svg object it is not working as `<image>` tag is creating problem.

ERROR Message:: SVGElemImage: failed to open image "http://174.138.12.68:4000/uploads/products/1597070187552-Ash%20Back.jpg" in PDFKit

My SVG data:::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" xml:space="preserve">
<desc>Created with Fabric.js 2.7.0</desc>
<defs>
</defs>
<g transform="matrix(0.31 0 0 0.31 200 200)"  >
    <image style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;"  xlink:href="http://174.138.12.68:4000/uploads/products/1597070187552-Ash%20Back.jpg" x="-512" y="-640" width="1024" height="1280"></image>
</g>
<g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 206.5 263.5)"  >
<rect style="stroke: rgb(0,0,255); stroke-width: 3; stroke-dasharray: 7 7; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(230,230,230); fill-opacity: 0.8; fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 0.2;"  x="-100" y="-100" rx="0" ry="0" width="200" height="200" />
</g>
<g clip-path="url(#CLIPPATH_4)"  >
<g transform="matrix(0.9 0 0 0.9 205 244.88)"  >
<clipPath id="CLIPPATH_4" >
    <rect transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 206.5 263.5)" x="-100" y="-100" rx="0" ry="0" width="200" height="200" />
</clipPath>
    <image style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;"  xlink:href="http://174.138.12.68:4000/transparent_images/1598349009675-1589379674035GoogleFiveStarCust.Rating.pdf-1.svg" x="-111" y="-92" width="222" height="184"></image>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think remote image import is still not implemented. What you can do is download the image and replace the path in the svg and export. This is working for me since my original svg referenced local image I didn't had this issue.